# ITestContainerDiscoverer not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I have a Visual Studio Unittest-Adapter which is working well for Visual Studio 2013 so far. Tests are extracted using a custom command `ctest -N` and thus a implementation of `ITestContainerDiscoverer` is needed.

You can check out the project here: https://github.com/micst/CTestTestAdapter

**As it seems, Visual Studio 2015 simply ignores the `ITestContainerDiscoverer` implementation** or at least never instantiates and uses it. If I remove the container discoverer from my project and add the default file extensions `.dll` and `.exe` to the `ITestDiscoverer`, so the VSIX in general is correctly installed and working.

How can I get the `ITestContainerDiscoverer` to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some (re)search I managed to solve my problem:

1.

There is one unittest adapter example for XML files out there which works on VS2015, so I was able to track down my problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bhuvaneshwari/archive/2012/03/13/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-test-adapter.aspx

2.

It seems like the signature of the constructor of my ITestContainerDiscoverer was wrong. While my original test container discoverer had a constructor without any parameters, the one used in the XML example used a bunch of parameters. After some testing it seems like you need at least a IServiceProvider as constructor parameter:

```
public CTestContainerDiscoverer(
    [Import(typeof (SVsServiceProvider))] IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
```

No idea why exactly, but I think this solved it. It's actually quite sad how bad the documentation for the unittest adapter interfaces is.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to do this - 6 years on now it seems - and I can confirm that it is still and absolute nightmare to navigate. And I'm trying to write a test adapter for tests written in C# - but with a custom execution plan. There must be maybe 10 of us in total who have ever tried to write a test adapter haha

Comment: 2023 (almost 2024) checking in... still having a terrible time.